# trying to loop over the div and get all checkboxes and add label to to it

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I am trying to get into a piece of code with javascript to find all the checkboxes and add name to it and then add a label attribute to it with somecss so the accessibility can work

my code is like this

```
<tr class="el-table__row">
   <td rowspan="1" colspan="1" class="el-table_1_column_1  selection-center ">
      <div class="cell">
         <span class="selection">
            <label class="el-checkbox">
               <span class="el-checkbox__input"><span class="el-checkbox__inner"></span><input type="checkbox" aria-hidden="false" class="el-checkbox__original" value="1"></span>
               <span class="el-checkbox__label">
                  1<!---->
               </span>
            </label>
         </span>
      </div>
   </td>
   <td rowspan="1" colspan="1" class="el-table_1_column_2  undefined el-table__expand-column ">
      <div class="cell">
         <div class="el-table__expand-icon"><i class="el-icon el-icon-arrow-right"></i></div>
      </div>
   </td>
   <td rowspan="1" colspan="1" class="el-table_1_column_3  textClickable ">
      <div class="cell"><a href="">51436215</a></div>
   </td>
</tr>
```

my JS i am trying like this

```
document.querySelectorAll('el-table__body .el-table__row').forEach(function (item, v) {
    var chks = document.getElementsByClassName('el-checkbox__original');
for (var i = 0; i < chks.length; i++) {
    chks[i].name = 'check_' + item.innerHTML;
}    
      });
```

i am trying to get the end results like this

```
<tr class="el-table__row">
   <td rowspan="1" colspan="1" class="el-table_1_column_1  selection-center ">
      <div class="cell">
         <span class="selection">
            <label class="el-checkbox">
               <span class="el-checkbox__input"><span class="el-checkbox__inner"></span><input type="checkbox" aria-hidden="false" class="el-checkbox__original" value="1" name="check_1"></span>
               <span class="el-checkbox__label">
                  1<!---->
               </span>
        <label for="check_1" style="position:absolute;z-index:-9999;">select this row</label>
            </label>
         </span>
      </div>
   </td>
   <td rowspan="1" colspan="1" class="el-table_1_column_2  undefined el-table__expand-column ">
      <div class="cell">
         <div class="el-table__expand-icon"><i class="el-icon el-icon-arrow-right"></i></div>
      </div>
   </td>
   <td rowspan="1" colspan="1" class="el-table_1_column_3  textClickable ">
      <div class="cell"><a href="">51436215</a></div>
   </td>
</tr>
```

I want to add the `name="check_1"` to the checkbox, it will unique because its going to be under a loop

and then after the span tag, I am trying to add this

```
<label for="check_1" style="position:absolute;z-index:-9999;">select this row</label>
```

but i am not sure how to get to the labale tag after the span tag.

can anyone guide

Comment: how many checkboxes are there in a row with the class name `'el-checkbox__original'`

Comment: only 1 checkbox per row

Comment: and every checkbox has same class

Comment: Your desired code example has a label element nested within a label element. This is invalid and you should not do this.

Comment: The question is tagged `vue.js` -- if you're using that framework, you *absolutely should not* be rummaging around in the DOM making direct modifications Vue doesn't know about; your changes will get overwritten in the next render, or may remove data bindings Vue is depending on.

Comment: (and if you are not using that framework, you should delete that tag from the question so you don't attract more lectures like mine :)

Answer (score 2):

Try something like this:

```js
document.querySelectorAll('.el-checkbox__original').forEach((input, index) => {
  const uniqueName = `check_${index}`;
  input.name = uniqueName;  
  
  input.closest('.el-checkbox').insertAdjacentHTML('beforeend', `<span>select this row</span>`);
});
```

```html
<tr class="el-table__row">
   <td rowspan="1" colspan="1" class="el-table_1_column_1  selection-center ">
      <div class="cell">
         <span class="selection">
            <label class="el-checkbox">
               <span class="el-checkbox__input"><span class="el-checkbox__inner"></span><input type="checkbox" aria-hidden="false" class="el-checkbox__original" value="1"></span>
               <span class="el-checkbox__label">
                  1<!---->
               </span>
            </label>


         </span>
      </div>
   </td>
   <td rowspan="1" colspan="1" class="el-table_1_column_2  undefined el-table__expand-column ">
      <div class="cell">
         <div class="el-table__expand-icon"><i class="el-icon el-icon-arrow-right"></i></div>
      </div>
   </td>
   <td rowspan="1" colspan="1" class="el-table_1_column_3  textClickable ">
      <div class="cell"><a href="">51436215</a></div>
   </td>
</tr>
```

**Notes:**

You should not nest a label within another label element. I changed the thing that you are appending to a span.

**References:**

[document.querySelectorAll](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll)

document.querySelectorAll browser [support](https://caniuse.com/?search=querySelectorAll)
[image]

[element.insertAdjacentHTML](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/insertAdjacentHTML)

element.insertAdjacentHTML browser [support](https://caniuse.com/?search=insertAdjacentHTML)
[image]

[element.closest](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/closest)

element.closest browser [support](https://caniuse.com/element-closest)
[image]

Note these are all browser native methods and are not jquery (or any other library)

Comment: but its jquery, i can't use that, i have to use javascript, because we are not using jquery library, can you please update your answer

Comment: This is not Jquery. Everything in my response is vanilla JS. See edits for links to documentation.